# Property wiring with AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource

Tags: autofac

I'm using AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource to register concrete types. Is there any way that I could also inject the properties of those types ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **No**

Because Autofac won't inject properties by default and the  `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource` provides no way to configure this.

However based on the [original implementation](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Core/Source/Autofac/Features/ResolveAnything/AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource.cs), you can create your own `AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSourceWithProperties` which registers the componenets with `PropertiesAutowired()` option:

```cs
public class AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSourceWithProperties 
    : IRegistrationSource
{
    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(
        Service service,
        Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        if (registrationAccessor == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("registrationAccessor");
        }
        var ts = service as TypedService;
        if (ts == null ||
            !ts.ServiceType.IsClass ||
            ts.ServiceType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Delegate)) ||
            ts.ServiceType.IsAbstract ||
            registrationAccessor(service).Any())
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();

        return new[] { RegistrationBuilder.ForType(ts.ServiceType)
            .PropertiesAutowired().CreateRegistration() };
    }

    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Then you register your implementation with:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
  .RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSourceWithProperties());
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - I just thought there would be a nicer way. Thank you.